# Create formatting wrapper for use with ToString

Tags: formatting

I'd like to create a custom number format for use with `ToString`. However if I do the obvious and create a function that calls `NumberForm` with modified options:

```
numberform = 
  NumberForm[#, 
    ExponentFunction -> (If[-5 < # < 5, Null, #]&), 
    NumberFormat -> (If[#3 != "", SequenceForm[#1, "E", #3],#1]&)]&
```

> ```
> Slot[1]&
> ```

It works fine as a function:

```
numberform[1234567890.]
```

> ```
> 1.23457E9
> ```

but not with `ToString`:

```
ToString[1234567890., numberform]
```

> ```
> ToString[1.23457*10^9, Slot[1]&]
> ```

Is there some attribute I have to set to make it behave like the built-in forms? Is that even possible? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `TagSet` (`/:`). This attaches the definition to `numberform` instead of `ToString`:

```
ClearAll[numberform];
numberformFunction = 
  NumberForm[#, ExponentFunction -> (If[-5 < # < 5, Null, #] &), 
    NumberFormat -> (If[#3 != "", 
    SequenceForm[#1, "E", #3], #1] &)] &;
numberform /: ToString[s_, numberform] := numberformFunction@s;
ToString[1234567890., numberform]
```

> 1.23457E9

Comment: That's an ingenious idea that I'm happy to have been exposed to, but mostly it reminded me that there was a trick not in the documention of ToString that I once knew and had forgotten: all I had to do in the first place was ToString[numberform[1234567890.]]. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply

```
numberform = 
 NumberForm[ToExpression@#, 
   ExponentFunction -> (If[-5 < # < 5, Null, #] &), 
   NumberFormat -> (If[#3 != "", SequenceForm[#1, "E", #3], #1] &)] &
```

???

```
numberform[ToString@123456.]
```

> 1.23456E5

```
numberform[123456.]
```

> 1.23456E5